# wp rest api custom end point with post request

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, wordpress-rest-api

i have a question concerning wp rest api custom endpoints
The idea is i am trying to update database on my local server with data from database on remote site.the data is for a settings page

I have succeeded in developing custom end points with GET  methods successfully and i have also succeeded in getting data from database to the get end point.

My question is with the post request. How do i develop the callback function to receive data from remote site and update local database.

Below is my code

```
function register_custom_route(){

    register_rest_route( 'silentblast-dashboard/v1', '/getsetting/(?P<id>\d+)', array(

   array(

   'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'retrieve_settings_data',

),

array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'update_settings_data',

)
));

}

function retrieve_settings_data($data){

$out = get_option( 'buddysettings');

return $out;


    }

function update_settings_data( $posts ){

}
```

Now secondly, i tried to add this to the retrieve_settings_data() function.

```
$url(remote url) = 'http://websiteproject.ca/blastbuilder/demo/wp-json/silentblast-dashboard/v1/getsetting/';

$response =  wp_remote_get( $url );

$posts = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

$posts = json_decode($posts);

$posts = (array) $posts;

$out = update_option( 'buddy_settings', $posts );

$outi = get_option( 'buddy_settings' );

         return $outi ;
```

and it worked to update the local database with data from remote database but it updates only after i refresh the link localhost/wordpress/wp-json/silentblast-dashboard/v1/getsetting/ on the browser which is quite funny to me. This means if i change settings on spage. the remote database gets updated and posts its data to its endpoint  remotesite.com/wp-json/silentblast-dashboard/v1/getsetting/ now the code actually gets the setting data from the remote custom route and updates the local database but i can only see the updates in the browser after reloading the custom route for my local site.